# Is there any known reason for QGIS recurrently crashing in windows7?

Tags: qgis

I use (and been a big fan of) QGIS daily for 7 months now, and only recently - past couple weeks - been experiencing problems with QGIS recurrently crashing. This is even more serius cause it happens when i try to save the editions I'm doing.
I'm using a windows7 machine and i'm performing the same task for 2 months now which consists on visually interpreting a satellite image to digitalize features to a shapefile. I haven't change anything and I don't understand why this occurs but it's very annoying to have QGIS crashing every half an hour...
Any ideas? similar experiences?

Thanks,
Vasco Nunes

PS: I'm using version 1.7.3 but this has been happening since I had 1.7.2

Comment: Hi Vasco, please give us more details. It crashes doing a particular operation with a specific datasource? The crashes are random? They happen when handling rasters? vectors? what datasource (shapes, postgis, grass, etc.)? Are you using the standalone or the osgeo4w installer? Did you tested the qgis-dev release you can install with the osgeo4w installer?

Comment: The crashes are random? - Sort of... I'm editing the shapefile and after about one hour or less and, say, 10 or 15 saves, it just crashes when i try to save the edits again -- They happen when handling rasters? vectors? what datasource (shapes, postgis, grass, etc.)? - handling shapefiles -- Are you using the standalone or the osgeo4w installer? - I'm using osgeo4w installer -- Did you tested the qgis-dev release you can install with the osgeo4w installer? - no, i haven't test it yet --

Comment: Then test qgis-dev, it is important to know if the issue was already solved and if the fix can be backported in time for 1.7.4

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found out I had problems in my shapefile - some features were corrupted. I cleaned it with Grass and QGIS haven't been crashing since then...

Comment: Hi Vasco. QGIS should not crash anyway, can you post a sample of the original data that causes the crash?

Comment: can you share details like nature of corruption and which Grass tools you used ? It will be helpful for all. Thanks .

Answer (score 4):

The beauty of open source software is that bugs are tracked and available to see for anyone who's interested.

In your case you should start by looking at the list of blocking bugs:

http://hub.qgis.org/projects/quantum-gis/issues?query_id=23

and might as well try a query with *causes crash or corruption*: yes